# Using EF with connected POCOs in multi-tier applications

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ioc-container, poco

I am developing a multi tier desktop application(Onion architecture), with a `WinForm` Project as `UI`, and I used `EF code first` to access my `DB`, and for my Domain models, I want to use `POCO`s, so I have two choices :

- Connected `POCO`s
- Disconnected `POCO`s

If I use disconnected `POCO`s I have to do a lot of stuff outside of EF and do not use EF features, because:

- I have to save and manage entity's `State` in client side
- When I want save changes to DB, I have to sync client side `POCO`'s `State`
  with `DbContext` entity's `State`.
- During adding `POCO`s to newly created `DbContext`, I have to control 
  to prevent adding two entities with same key to the `DbContext`.

So, it seems normal, to use Connected `POCO`s, but in this situation I think I have the following challenges:

- If I want to manage lifetime of my `DbContext` using an `IoC` container, in a multiuser
  environment, and keep alive the `DbContexts` for all users from time their
  getting `POCO`s to time that saving back their changes to DB, it take large
  amount of server memory, I think, and it isn't efficient.
- I want to save below related graph of my entities in one transaction
  [image]

I have these questions:

1. How can I use connected `POCO`s in a my multitier application?
2. which config should I use to manage lifetime of my `DbContext`s using `IoC container`s in my case?
3. Is there any way to make(or change) the total graph(in client side) and then pass it to save in `DbContext`?
4. Is there any sample that implement this situations?

Comment: For item 3 on your list you can vote for better support for working with disconnected entities here:https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864 (and you could look at the 3rd party solution discussed there)